# What's the difference between sharing a semaphore between threads of a process and sharing one between processes?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

I am currently learning POSIX threads and working on getting to grips with concurrency as a whole. I am now looking at the man page for [`sem_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html). It takes an argument to define whether the semaphore passed to it is to be shared between threads (zero) or to be shared between processes (non zero). Could somebody give me a good explanation of the differences here. I think I understand the basics but some advice and clarification would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the difference should be more or less obvious from `man sem_init`:

- If `pshared == 0` then the semaphore will not be visible outside the current process, and it will likely be automatically destroyed when this process is finished. Therefore, it will only be useful to synchronize between threads that belong to this process, and since threads always share memory, the `sem` argument can be used directly by any thread, without further actions.
- If `pshared != 0` then this semaphore will be available to other processes, provided they can access the memory pointed to by `sem`. For that you will need either shared memory or inherit it by using `fork()` *after* creating the semaphore. Also, if you don't explicitly destroy the semaphore, in some implementations (I don't know which ones) the semaphore may leak.

Of course, you can use a *non-zero-pshared* semaphore to synchronize threads and just ignore the process part. But process semaphores use more resources, usually an OS object, while thread semaphores usually can be implemented 100% in userland; so doing that is just wasting resources.